# alert('Hello ${this.state.parentName}') instaed of printing hello parent, it is printing Hello ${this.state.parentName}

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, string

This is the code of ReactJs , I don't understand the problem.

I am expecting some support

Comment: Using the [wrong quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: "I am expecting some support" is pretty demanding, by the way. Do remember nobody's here to serve you specifically.

Comment: @tadman It's probably because of this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424310/can-the-text-in-the-ask-question-wizard-asking-the-op-to-describe-what-they-were

Answer (score 1):

Justt change `'` to `. You need to use string template properly.

```
// chnage
// alert('Hello ${this.state.parentName}')
// to 

alert(`Hello ${this.state.parentName}`)
```